# The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: ios, react-native, build

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/Developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newtest-

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/Developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newtest-agxjpntdwitxtlcyhpzcympsamhl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-5F4C70EF7D90A5A5BDAEB404279F232A.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.